# How to merge two Pandas DataFrames when two columns are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dataframes:

```
  orderItemId     orderId                  orderDate         latestDeliveryDate  
0  BFC0000332253518  2648507110  2019-11-10T21:08:30+01:00  2019-11-11T00:00:00+01:00  
0  BFC0000332123047  2647717360  2019-11-10T15:42:39+01:00  2019-11-11T00:00:00+01:00  
0  BFC0000332291194  2648712140  2019-11-10T22:24:56+01:00  2019-11-11T00:00:00+01:00 

          orderItemId     orderId shipmentId   shipmentReference               shipmentDate
0    BFC0000332253518  2648507110  689508122  081234500926730318  2019-11-11T00:10:06+01:00
1    BFC0000332123047  2647717360  689505054  081234500926572451  2019-11-10T23:55:38+01:00
2    BFC0000332291194  2648712140  689505045  081234500926710549  2019-11-10T23:55:37+01:00
```

How can I merge those together with Pandas merge? Because they have two columns that are the same. Can I use multiple `on=` values?

Comment: use `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['orderItemId','orderId'])`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use multiple `on` values. I suppose from your example above, you want to merge on `orderItemId` and `orderId` right?

Just use:

```
final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', left_on = ['orderItemId','orderId'], right_on = ['orderItemId','orderId'])
```